# Flutter load all Network Images on Custom Splash Screen or Loading Screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I am using flutter web and i want to load all network images to load on startup and till then show Loading Screen.

more - the provided methods include using **cacheNetworking** packages but still the thing is I want them to load while showing Loading Screen and use them as some kind of Image variable.

Comment: use `precacheImage()` top level function then